# add data attribute di wordpress body

Tags: wordpress, learndash

using the code below, it doesn't add an attribute but everything is inserted as a class of the body, how can I fix it?

```
function edi_custom_body_attributes( $classes ) {

    if (is_singular('sfwd-lessons')) {

        $classes[] = 'data-tipology="lesson"';

    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'edi_custom_body_attributes');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `body_class` hook to add the additional attributes like the following.

```
function custom_attr_classes( $classes )
{
    $classes[] = '" data-x="scroll" data-target=".navbar';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','custom_attr_classes', 999 );
```

Hope it helps.